# is the output of the PHP Facebook API JSON parsable?

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

If I issue `$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');`, is the output in JSON format?

Also, where can I find the complete list of API strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the facebook php api will return an associative array, as such `$friends` will contain an assoc array of all friends for the current user. (it uses standard json_decode to accomplish this - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

as mentioned by Rafiq + others, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ is the api reference you would be after, and the graph api explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a great resource for viewing the expected JSON output of api calls .(keeping in mind the php sdk will return this as an assoc array

Answer (score 0):

API 'commands' are GET and POST but I guess you're looking for the list of fields/tables.

You should use the Graph Explorer to browse through this list and see what's available.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explore

It is also useful to see what tables are available via FQL instead of the Graph API, as the API hasn't been updated to include all functionality yet:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook returns the `json` but php sdk converts in associative array. 
 So, `$friends` would be an `array`.
Do this,

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
var_dump($friends);
```

It will give every info related about fields which `$friends` has.

If you are looking for other api methods,

Look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

*Also, dont write an answer, just update your question in case you need to say something more*